# image to data uri conversion

Tags: php, mpdf, data-uri

I have written a Javascript which can preview the Imgae in a IMG tag. Now I want the data uri format of this image so that I can display it using mPDF.

The following is the IMG ID tag in php file

```
<div class="logo_prev">
                            <img id="img_prev"  alt="Your logo" class="img-thumbnail invoice-logo img-responsive"/>
                        </div>
                        <br>
                        <input type='file' onchange="logoImg(this);" name="invoice_logo" class="select-logo" data-validation="mime size" data-validation-allowing="jpg, png, gif" data-validation-max-size="2M" data-validation-error-msg="Only jpg, gif or png are allowed (Max 2mb)" />
```

The Javascript code is

```
function logoImg(input) {
  if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
  var reader = new FileReader();

  reader.onload = function (e) {
    $('#img_prev')
    .attr('src', e.target.result);
  };

  reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
}
```

and I have written the code like the following:

```
$image = $_POST['img_prev'];

$imageData = base64_encode(file_get_contents($image));

$src = 'data: '.mime_content_type($image).';base64,'.$imageData;
```

Now I want to access this `$src` variable in the PHP file. But it shows me nothing in that variable.

Comment: your using $_POST but your not even submitting anything,?

Comment: @OliSoproniB.ok....so how can I access the Image from the IMG tag???

Comment: can you also post your javascript code.

Comment: You have to post this data from your page to access it in PHP. Take a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: @OliSoproniB.sure...I just have edited the code...please check once

Comment: @RauliRajande...ok but how to access that function value in php variable...am confused